# SQL limiting the output to a number of results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query.

**SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID IN ('UK', 'Germany');**

This outputs the results to show all customers in UK and Germany, but as you can imagine, there will be loads of outputs, and I just require it to output 2 results for UK and 2 results for Germany?

Is this possible?

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE tagid = 'UK' LIMIT 2) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE tagid = 'Germany' LIMIT 2)` should work

Comment: @B001ᛦ That's not correct, he wants two from UK and two from Germeny, so total of 4

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for the solutions, however this works, but the function 'Limit 2' breaks the query. Any other way around it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What database are you actually using?

Give us the whole SQL you are currently trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL` comes to mind:

```
(SELECT c.*
 FROM Customer c
 WHERE TAGID = 'UK'
 LIMIT 2
) UNION ALL
(SELECT c.*
 FROM Customer c
 WHERE TAGID = 'Germany'
 LIMIT 2
);
```

Note that this can take advantage of an index on`Customer(TagID)`.  Also, this returns two *arbitrary* rows.  You can use an `ORDER BY` to return the newest, oldest, biggest, smallest, reddest, bluest or whatever.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2a20257e718ef4d81e21cd5b0ff1c7e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for the solutions, however this works, but the function 'Limit 2' breaks the query. Any other way around it?

Comment: @AndyThomas . . . This works fine in MySQL.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The Limit 2 didn't work, however the function TOP worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @AndyThomas . . . Then the MySQL tag is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. Please check below methods.

Method 1 :

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID ='UK'
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID = 'Germany'
```

Method 2:

```
(SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID ='UK' LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID = 'Germany' LIMIT 2)
```

Method 3:

```
(SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID ='UK' AND ROWNUM = 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE TAGID = 'Germany' AND ROWNUM = 2)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for the solutions, however this works, but the function 'Limit 2' I have also tired ROWNUM breaks the query. Any other way around it?